# How to write a search pattern to include a space in findstr?

Tags: regex, findstr

I want to search all files in a certain directory for occurrences of statements such as

```
  Load frmXYZ
```

I am on Windows 7, using the `findstr` command. I tried:

```
  findstr /n Load.*frm *.*
```

But this gives me unwanted results such as:

```
 If ABCFormLoaded Then Unload frmPQR
```

So I tried to put a blankspace between `Load` and `frm` and gave the command like this:

```
 findstr /n Load frm *.*
```

But this simply searched for all occurrences of the word `load` or all occurrences of the word `frm`. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Aren't you missing the `/r` option to enable regexes, anyway?

Comment: It says /r uses search strings as regular expressions. So does it mean that "space" will then be treated as part of the regular expression? Let me try.

Comment: Ok, I tried, but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: This is a few years stale, but I generally just use `.` instead of space, since most of the time I care about the other letters in the expression by position and whether the space is really a space isn't as important.  `findstr /n /r Load.frm *.*` (Don't get me wrong, `/c` is useful, but half the time it doesn't seem to work for me anyways)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you use spaces, you need the `/C:` option to pass the the literal string(s) to the regex `/R` option.
Once the it gets to the regex, it's treated as a regex.

That said, this is typical MS trash.

### Use two regex search strings

The bottom line is that you have to use 2 strings to handle cases where
`Load frm` is at the beginning like so:

- `Load frm apples bananas carrots`

OR in the middle like so:

- `some other text Load frm and more`.

### Version without character classes

Below is using XP sp3, windows 7 may be different, both are trash!

`findstr /N /R /C:"  *Load  *frm" /C:"^Load  *frm" test.txt`

```
7:Load frm is ok    
8:    Load     frm is ok
```

#### Mind the Colon

**NOTE:** The colon in `/C:` is MANDATORY for this to work.

If you leave out the colon then `findstr`'s error handling is just to treat `/C` as an invalid option, ignore that invalid option and go ahead anyway. Leading to unexpected and unwanted output.

### Equivalent version using character classes

`findstr /N /R /C:"[ ][ ]*Load[ ][ ]*frm" /C:"^Load[ ][ ]*frm" test.txt`

#### Character classes breakdown

```
// The first regex search string breaks down like this:
[ ]   // require 1 space
[ ]*  // optional many spaces
Load  // literal 'Load'
[ ]   // require 1 space
[ ]*  // optional many spaces
frm   // literal 'frm'

// The second regex search string breaks down like this:
^     // beginning of line
Load  // literal 'Load'
[ ]   // require 1 space
[ ]*  // optional many spaces
frm   // literal 'frm'
```

A real regex might be `\bLoad\s+frm`

Comment: Thanks!! So helpful. Ok, what is a "trash"?

Comment: Oh, I thought it was some technical term!

Comment: If it is trash, honestly I can't see the point in answering to such questions. Unless you are a dustman.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud - Even trash has to be handled. Hey, look at that, it's trash: `have to use 2 strings to handle cases where
 'Load frm' is at the beginning OR in the middle`

Comment: Looks like that character class thing does not work on Windows 10 any more: `echo 1.999 K| findstr /R "\....[ ]K"`

Answer (score 34):

Use the `/c` option:

```
findstr /n /c:"Load frm" *.*
```

From the help (`findstr /?`):

```
/C:string  Uses specified string as a literal search string.
```

Comment: What if there is more than one blank space between "Load" and "frm"?

Comment: `[ ]+`. But you'd need to use `/r`, too to enable regexes.

Comment: I tried findstr /n /r /c:"Load[]+ frm" followed by asterisk dot asterisk. But now it shows nothing.

Comment: Findstr has its own lame little implementation of regex. It does not include '+' as a metacharacter.

Comment: Well, then use `[ ][ ]*`. Regexes don't strictly need `+`.

Answer (score 10):

## Use word delimiter regex

I used the the special `\<` "beginning of word" regex symbol.

I tried this on the Win10 version of findstr. But according to Microsoft this special [`\<` symbol has been in `findstr.exe` ever since WinXP](https://archive.is/N1U7Q#selection-3787.0-3797.32).

Full (and painful) breakdown of many options that do NOT work below.

At the very bottom: what actually worked.

#### The sample file itself

```
C:\>type lines.txt
Load frmXYZ                         // This line should match.
If ABCFormLoaded Then Unload frmPQR // This line should NOT match.
pears Load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
                                    // This blank line should NOT match.
LOAD FRMXYZ                         // This line should match.
IF ABCFORMLOADED THEN UNLOAD FRMPQR // This line should NOT match.
PEARS LOAD FRM GRAPES PINEAPPLES    // This line should match.
                                    // This blank line should NOT match.
load frmxyz                         // This line should match.
if abcformloaded then unload frmpqr // This line should NOT match.
pears load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
```

#### Wrong. With regular execution space is treated as delimiter.

```
C:\>type lines.txt | findstr /N "Load frm"
1:Load frmXYZ                         // This line should match.
2:If ABCFormLoaded Then Unload frmPQR // This line should NOT match.
3:pears Load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
9:load frmxyz                         // This line should match.
10:if abcformloaded then unload frmpqr // This line should NOT match.
11:pears load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
```

#### Wrong: With Regex option space is STILL treated as delimiter.

```
C:\>type lines.txt | findstr /N /R "Load frm"
1:Load frmXYZ                         // This line should match.
2:If ABCFormLoaded Then Unload frmPQR // This line should NOT match.
3:pears Load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
9:load frmxyz                         // This line should match.
10:if abcformloaded then unload frmpqr // This line should NOT match.
11:pears load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
```

#### More right but still wrong. With /C option we now get preserved spaces but don't find other character cases.

```
C:\>type lines.txt | findstr /N /R /C:"Load frm"
1:Load frmXYZ                         // This line should match.
3:pears Load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
```

#### Wrong. /I for "Ignore Case" does not help. We get matches from within words we did not want.

```
C:\>type lines.txt | findstr /N /R /I /C:"Load frm"
1:Load frmXYZ                         // This line should match.
2:If ABCFormLoaded Then Unload frmPQR // This line should NOT match.
3:pears Load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
5:LOAD FRMXYZ                         // This line should match.
6:IF ABCFORMLOADED THEN UNLOAD FRMPQR // This line should NOT match.
7:PEARS LOAD FRM GRAPES PINEAPPLES    // This line should match.
9:load frmxyz                         // This line should match.
10:if abcformloaded then unload frmpqr // This line should NOT match.
11:pears load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
```

## Right. Use special "Beginning of word" regex symbol. Matches beginning-of-line or space.

### Either case sensitive:

```
C:\>type lines.txt | findstr /N /R /C:"\<Load frm"
1:Load frmXYZ                         // This line should match.
3:pears Load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
```

### or ignoring case

```
C:\>type lines.txt | findstr /N /R /I /C:"\<Load frm"
1:Load frmXYZ                         // This line should match.
3:pears Load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
5:LOAD FRMXYZ                         // This line should match.
7:PEARS LOAD FRM GRAPES PINEAPPLES    // This line should match.
9:load frmxyz                         // This line should match.
11:pears load frm grapes pineapples    // This line should match.
```

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code will only allow letters, numbers, underscore and white space in keyword:

```
set /p keyword="Enter keyword: " || Set keyword=

set keyword_replaced=%keyword: =_%

echo %keyword_replaced%| findstr /r "[^0-9a-zA-Z_]" > nul
if errorlevel 1 goto noexit
echo special characters in keyword not allowed (except space and _), TERMINATING
timeout 4
exit /b 0
:noexit
```