# Findstr with spaces does not work with character class

Tags: regex, cmd

I have read [How to write a search pattern to include a space in findstr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789563/how-to-write-a-search-pattern-to-include-a-space-in-findstr) and I thought the character class should solve my problem.

I came up with the following minimal reproducible example:

```
echo 1.999 K| findstr /R "\....[ ]K"
```

I expect `\.` to match the dot, `...` to match 999, `[ ]` to match the space and `K` to match K. However, there's no output.

When I do

```
echo 1.999 K| findstr /R "\.... K"
```

it will be interpreted as 2 individual search terms, which I can't use, because I need the K to be after the number (compare to `echo K 1.999 M| findstr /R "\.... K"`)

I'm on Windows 10 1903 18362.1016 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `/R /C:"\....[ ]K"` works, as does `/R /C:"\.... K"`. I've personally long given up trying to understand `findstr`'s idiosyncrasies with parsing its arguments or regular expressions¹. If you don't have multiple search terms, using `/C:` should never do harm and only cut down on unexpected failures.

The other option, if you have it available, might be to pipe your data through PowerShell:

```
echo 1.999 K| powershell "$input -match '\....[ ]K'"
echo 1.999 K| pwsh -command  "$input -match '\....[ ]K'"
```

Slower (PowerShell 7 is quite a bit faster than 5.1), but a lot more predictable.

---

¹ [dbenham has reverse-engineered `findstr` once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/73070), with a list of all known bugs. My guess here would be that despite the `[]`, the space is still parsed as a separator between search terms, each of which then contain a literal bracket, leading to no match.

Comment: It is hard to say that `findstr` supports using a regex given its limited abilities. PowerShell has much better regex support.